# About Laravel 4 routing procedure/s

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

This code:

```
Redirect::to('dashboard/'.$SomeNameVariable.'/edit')
```

gives a result of `http://localhost/laravel-sample/public/dashboard/SomeName/settings` 
on my address bar and my route is

```
Route::get('dashboard/{id}/settings', 'CallerController@showDash');
```

The route gets any kind of name from a user according to Jeffrey Way's tutorial (his video tutorial was on Laravel 3.0 so this tutorial is not the latest). Is there a way for me to echo the value of {id}? the code snippets I have provided is on Laravel 4 I presume FYI.

Comment: What does your controller code look like?

Comment: hi @AustinMullins here is the link for the pastebin http://laravel.io/bin/XO5YB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In CallerController's showDash method, you can do this:

```
public function showDash($id)
{
    // dd($id);
    // dd(compact('id'));
    return View::make('blade.file.here')->with(compact('id'));
}
```

And in your view, it will be available as $id.

Uncomment those lines as you like to see what's going on. You could also do `withId($id)` or `with('id', $id)`, but I like the compact method myself.